# How to visit a serialized clang abstract syntax tree (AST)

Tags: c++, abstract-syntax-tree, clang++, libtooling

I've been able to implement an `ASTFrontendAction` to create an `ASTConsumer`, which uses a `RescursiveASTVisitor` to traverse a translation unit decl, thereby visiting all the nodes of an AST for a given source file.  I do this by implementing a `ToolAction` which is passed to `ClangTool::run(ToolAction *action)`.  This tool overrides the `ToolAction::runInvocation` member function to do some processing between each call to my `ASTFrontendAction`.  So far so good, everything is working as expected, and my custom clang tool is helping me better explore a rather large, over 15 years old code base.

However, every time I want to run my tool, I need to do a full blown parse of the ASTs.  As I mentioned, this is a rather large code base, so it takes a while to do a single run.  I have gathered, by looking through the code, that it is possible to create and traverse an AST from a saved file, rather than perform the parse.  Googling around confirmed that it's possible to save an AST, and by looking at the `ClangTool` and `ASTUnit` API, it seems it's pretty easy to do.

While it seems straightforward to *save* the AST, I have no idea how to *make use* of a saved AST when running my custom clang tool.  Looking at the code path for running a tool, I see there is a point where the AST is created either by parsing a source file or by reading it from a file.  What I would like to do is have all my ASTs available in a file(s), so that each run of my tool will create the ASTs from a file, and not need to perform a full parse (which, I assume would be much faster).

Could someone please help?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you see the [`ReadAST()`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ASTReader.html#af2f0d7be2a912c0423fd541d6d746675) function? Might be of some help if you hadn't already seen it.

Comment: I had not seen that, thanks for pointing me to it.

Comment: Though, I'm still a little confused.  To use this, I need an instance of `ASTReader`.  It's not clear to me how to get one.  Can I create my own? Can something provide one for me, if so, what is that thing?

Once I have an instance of the `ASTReader`, I think I could use it how I envision.  Just pick up all the saved ASTs, read them, and use my `ASTConsumer` to traverse the translation unit.  But is this really the only way?  I find it odd that there is no way to go through this same process using the normal tooling pipeline.

Comment: Did you find out how to use AST writer and reader?

Comment: Roberts's answer worked for me. However, make sure that the versions of Clang that generate the AST and develop the ClangTool are consistent. Otherwise, you will get a PCH format error.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
clang::CompilerInstance CI;
CI.createDiagnostics();
std::shared_ptr<clang::TargetOptions> TO = std::make_shared<clang::TargetOptions>();
TO->Triple = "x86_64-pc-win32"; // see clang -v
CI.setTarget(clang::TargetInfo::CreateTargetInfo(CI.getDiagnostics(), TO));

std::unique_ptr<ASTUnit> ast = ASTUnit::LoadFromASTFile("TheAstFile.ast", 
    CI.getPCHContainerReader(), 
    ASTUnit::LoadEverything, 
    &CI.getDiagnostics(), 
    CI.getFileSystemOpts());

MyAstConsumer consumer(ast->getASTContext());
consumer.HandleTranslationUnit(ast->getASTContext());
```